# Using pgfmath results in pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, pgfmath

I'm trying to create a simple variable system using pgfkeys, but I want to be able to create new "var" using other var, see this MWE where I have tried to use \pgfmathprintnumber. I thought the problem might be that that inputting \pgfmathresult directly was causing trouble.

```
\newcommand{\var}[2]{
\pgfmathparse{#2}
\pgfkeys{/var/#1/.initial=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\newcommand{\get}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/var/#1}
}


\begin{document}
    ...
    
    \var{a}{2+2}
    \get{a} % 4.0
    
    \var{a}{\get{a}+5} % (this will break)
    \get{a} % expected: 9.0
\end{document}
```

The purpose would be to use these values in coordinates with large TikZ procedures, such that I don't need to \def giant calculations repeatedly.

Comment: Suggestion: look at `declare function` syntax. It's much handier

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you explore the `declare function` syntax. You can use the variables and functions you define in every field that is evaluated by `pgfmath`, which makes them very handy.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={
    a1=3.14;
    dopp(\x)=2*\x;
    b=dopp(a1);
    }
}
\pgfmathparse{b+1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
\end{document}
```

...although is true that that kind of "variables" are not easily redefined, see the OP's comment below. So you can use a fully expandable approach (you can probably wrap it into some functions like  `get` and `set`, with either `etoolbox` or a bit of LaTeX3 magic, no time now):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
    \edef\varA{\fpeval{2+2}}
    \varA

    \edef\varA{\fpeval{\varA+5}}
    \varA
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*PS please post a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time!*

Comment: There appears to be no way to give b a new value after it is set. I'm not sure a variable system for TikZ should find its basis in a function system. Besides, this appears to be the same as \pgfkeys{/tikz/dopp (...)} with extra steps, but similar problems.